# Is it possible to configure Reportng, to display the output for multiple execution on the same test method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, reportng

I am trying to read multiple rows from a csv and execute it using one single test method. For instance, In Create User, I could create multiple users for each row using a single test method.

Now the question is, how to configure reportng to display the status of multiple execution on the same method?

Comment: Consider TestNG which has better reporting

Comment: @MrunalGosar I'm using Testng but reporting doesn't looks good with testng, so reportng was a plugin suggested which has better ui

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [extentreports](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/) or [allure reports](http://allure.qatools.ru/). They are far better than reportNG as well and have got great deal in customizing reports.

Comment: With ExtentReports you can use ExtentX so don't have to setup allure